# What's the meaning of "all too often", for example, in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does "all too often" mean in this sentence?

> A poorly designed distribution system can ruin the performance of any water-based system. **All too often**, people, including heating professionals, focus their attention on water-based heat source selection and simply assume that heat source ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *all* is frequently added to strengthen an expression. It means *entirely*, *thoroughly*, *very*, *completely*, *totally*, *much*.

- I was all alone
- The rum is all gone!
- He was all too happy to see me in trouble!

Answer (score 2):

According to NOAD, *all too* is an expression — "used to emphasize that something is the case to an extreme or unwelcome extent:

> *failures are all too common.*"

Answer (score -2):

"all too often" means simply "in most cases"

Comment: I'm afraid that it doesn't. Do you have a source for this statement?